# Sending data to the web service

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an application that requires storing data on an internet database.

Because of WP7 doesn't support databases,I think if I send my variables-datas to the web services that i craated,i can do what i want.

I know how to write a webservice but how can i send my variables to the webservice from WP7?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://www.sterlingdatabase.com/ which provides a nice and lightweight database. I'm also using this in my project and it works fine.

Comment: yeah i know about it but i have to save my data to the web database,can sterling db do that?

Comment: No, it only saves data to the isolated storage.